# Facebook JavaScript FQL query doesn't work and refreshes page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-fql

I have a JavaScript function to get Facebook page id. The problem is that the query doesn't seem to work and I don't know why. I've looked everywhere and found no solution.

I have initialised my FB API and everything.

```
function getID(link) {
  FB.api(
    {
      method: 'fql.query',
      query: 'SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url=' + link
    },
    function (response) {
      alert('the id is' + response[0].id);
    }
  );
}
```

I'm not seeing the alert when executing the function, but when I try to display only the alert('the id is') and not the "response[0].id" with it, I get the alert.

So basically the query is being executed but seem to return something weird that I cannot concatenate with my message,or is just ignored .

When I alert only the "response[0].id" element I get nothing at all, and by nothing I mean the function doesn't return anything and the rest of my page seems to work normally.

Comment: `"doesn't seem to work"` is really not enough information. Is the code reaching your callback? Are you seeing the alert? Are you certain that the link parameter is correct? Do you perhaps have some errors in your JS console from some other code?

Comment: sorry for my lack of details.
just updated my post.

Comment: What `response` are you getting?

Comment: i just updated my question with all the details.
thank you.

Comment: @sim - have you inspected the actual `response` object? What does it contain? You can view it using `console.log()` and it will appear in your JS console.

Comment: when i only do console.log(response[0]) i get : undefined 

,And when i do console.log(repsponse[0].id) i get : cannot read property id of undefined .

Comment: Do `console.log(response)` …